# How come some heavyweight pages scroll fluently while others don't?

Tags: html, performance, web-applications

What is degrading scroll performance while building websites?

My hypothesis is that it is about javascript resizing. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of sites disable native mouse scrolling and fallback to a javascript solution to make use of gpu acceleration. check this out -> http://paperandpaint.dk/ which is a great example. chrome in particular does not accelerate scrolling via mouse wheel which makes it appear choppy. Firefox on the other hand feels very different.

There are many great resources you can have a look:

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/scrolling/

I hope this gives you a little insight.

Cheers Tee

Answer (score 0):

Many, many things. Large DOM trees, having lots of enormous js files, large images that are resized, ads (big time), statically positioned elements that are repositioned using JavaScript on tablets, the list goes on, and on, and on. Basically, anything that is slow to render can and will degrade scrolling performance.